# Cassandra config as external DB, post installing TB Server

Tags: thingsboard

I already installed(default install) TB server on my local laptop,Windows10Pro64 and it is working fine.

Now, I'd like to install Cassandra and use it as an external DB for TB server.

Questions are :

1. should I edit the conf\thingsboard.yml for cassandra section and
   point to the Cassandra instance and restart the service?
2. do I have to reinstall the TB server , from the scratch?

Thanks

--M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to go with option one (change the conf/thingsboard.yml), however, the data you already have will be lost, obviously, due to change of the database. So, you will need to run the install script again.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I thought so.